# deleting matches from text file in php

Tags: php, regex

Consider a txt file of a list of items

qqqqqq

eeeeee

dddddd

hhhhhh

dddddd

hhhhhh

999999

And some of the items in the list are duplicates. how do I output a using php a text file where anything that is duplicated is removed.

the result:

qqqqqq

eeeeee

999999

Comment: It is better that you read everything, sort it, remove duplicate, then put it back.

Comment: sounds painfull, would you be better of using a db?

Comment: why would you use a database?  Load it into an array copy to another array excluding duplicates.  Done in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents('file.txt'); //get file to string
$row_array = explode("\n",$file); //cut string to rows by new line
$row_array = array_count_values(array_filter($row_array));

foreach ($row_array as $key=>$counts) {
    if ($counts==1)
        $no_duplicates[] = $key; 
}

//do what You want
echo '<pre>';
print_r($no_duplicates);

file_put_contents('no_duplicates.txt',$no_duplicates); //write to file. If file don't exist. Create it.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_unique`

and then right the content back

```
$file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");
$members = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
   $members[] = fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);
$unique_members = array(); 
$unique_members = array_unique($members);
var_dump($unique_members);
//write the content back to the file
```

The above solution was for removing the duplicates only and make them unique. Thanks to nhahtdh for pointing it out.

```
$count_members = array_count_values($members); 
foreach($count_members as $key=>$value)
{
   if($value == 1) 
       //write it to the file 
}
```

So you will not need the array_unique stuff 
Sorry again

Comment: -1. Not really keeping 1 copy, but remove all copies of items that have duplicate.

Comment: I don't undertand you but array_unique remove the duplicates and that what he wants

Comment: Check the output. `hhhhhh` and `dddddd` are removed.